# Unable to blackout whole months and years for calendarView component

Tags: windows, winui-3, calendarview

I am trying to make it so whole months and years are blackout'ed on my WinUI3 application, but for now I haven't been able to.

Our figma design is adamant that blackout months and years are a most helpful addition to our application, so I really want to deliver it.

For unique singular days, I was able to extract `CalendarViewDayItem` children from `CalendarView` and manage the `IsBlackout` property of them, but found out that there isn't any children named `CalendarViewMonthYearItem` for month or year objects.

I've tried blackin out every day on a month and on a year to see if the component would smartly handle it by automatically setting the `IsBlackout` property for months/years as true, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

After inspecting the application for more clarification of how the month objects are presented, I also noticed that they are considered to be `CalendarViewItem` objects as seen below:
[VisualTree For MonthItems showing a lot of CalendarViewItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZmYa.png)

Following that, I've tried to search specifically for that type of child objects within a CalendarView component, but it doesn't seem to be a valid recognizable object to work with as seen below:
[CalendarView autosuggest on visual studio not showing CalendarViewItem as an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLk0w.png)

I've run out of ideas for now, am I supposed to be doing something different here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to do this.

Let me show you an example about blacking out the header button.

```cs
private void SetCalendarViewHeaderButton(CalendarView calendarView, bool isBlackout)
{
    if (calendarView.FindDescendant<Button>(x => x.Name is "HeaderButton") is not Button headerButton ||
        headerButton.Parent is not Grid parentGrid ||
        headerButton.FindDescendant<TextBlock>() is not TextBlock contentTextBlock)
    {
        return;
    }
        
    if (isBlackout is false)
    {
        if (parentGrid.Children.OfType<Line>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name is "HeaderButtonBlackoutLine") is Line currentBlackoutLine)
        {
            parentGrid.Children.Remove(currentBlackoutLine);
        }

        headerButton.IsEnabled = true;
        return;
    }

    Line newBlackoutLine = new()
    {
        Name = "HeaderButtonBlackoutLine",
        Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray),
        StrokeThickness = 1,
    };

    newBlackoutLine.X1 = headerButton.Margin.Left + headerButton.Padding.Left;
    newBlackoutLine.X2 = newBlackoutLine.X1 + contentTextBlock.ActualWidth;
    newBlackoutLine.Y1 = headerButton.Margin.Top + headerButton.Padding.Top;
    newBlackoutLine.Y2 = newBlackoutLine.Y1 + contentTextBlock.ActualHeight;

    parentGrid.Children.Add(newBlackoutLine);
}
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue?